# Adding a jqGrid pager after Grid creation

Tags: jqgrid, pager

Does anybody know how adding a jqGrid pager after grid creation using 'tableToGrid' function?

Answer (score 0):

jqGrid uses internally the [setPager](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.3.1/js/grid.base.js#L1807-1919) function to make the most work for creating of the pager. The function `setPager` is *local* and can't be called from the outside.

If you need have in some situation the pager I would recommend you to create it always, but hide with respect of `$('#pager').hide()` till the pager will be needed. The grid with hidden pager looks exactly like the grid without pager.